# upgrade symfony 2.0 to 2.1 error to load symfony package

Tags: installation, version, composer-php

I have this error when I run composer.phar install :

> [RuntimeException]
>     Could not load package symfony/framework-standard-edition in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^2.4.8: Invalid version string "^2.4.8"

I use composer 1.0.0-alpha7 and I am upgrading my symfony project 2.0 to 2.1

This is my composer.json file :

> { "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
>       "license": "MIT",
>       "type": "project",
>       "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install":"symlink"
}
```

}

Have you an idea?

Comment: "S'il vous plaît poster votre question en anglais! Merci." [<==](https://translate.google.com/m/translate) "*Please post your question in English! Thank you.*"

Comment: Ok I translated my ask

Comment: Ok I find a problem : I remove "minimum-stability": "dev" of my composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find my problem : I just remove "minimum-stability": "dev" of my composer.json

Answer (score 4):

You have to run `composer selfupdate` as you're using a Composer version that doesn't yet understand the `^` operator in version constraints.